# Android instructions when open the application at first time?

Tags: android, android-layout, instructions

Do you know this [image]

Well I want create something like this screen. When I open for the first time the application I want open this screen and display a context.. How is possible? I don't know what search for this type of thing..

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

Comment: Thanks now i try. Hope is easy to use.

Comment: I also want same tutorial screen. Can i know which libs are you using to achieve this this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (isFirstTime()) {
        // What you do when the Application is Opened First time Goes here
    }
    ...
}


/***
 * Checks that application runs first time and write flag at SharedPreferences 
 * @return true if 1st time
 */
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {
        // first time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return !ranBefore;
}
```

Comment: so maybe i could use this library https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView and write what i need inside `isFirstTime`?

Comment: Write the above code as it is in your application You dont have to use any library

Comment: mmh.. well..it's not what i'm looking for.. but it could be another way..

Comment: Yes this could be one way, I have done with this method, You can also go with this.

Comment: It's not what i was looking for but it goes well.. so i accepted your answere

Comment: What was accepted here? I don't understand...

Comment: Be careful when reading the `RanBefore` value from one activity and writing it from another. `getPreferences` is private to each activity.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a nice library for showing a tutorial to the user about specific items on the screen, called "[ShowCase view library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView)" .

but the library quite buggy and sometimes puts its textural items outside the screen (for example when the device is rotated) .

the alternative similar library i've found is "[SuperToolTips](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips)" .

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MaterialShowcaseView https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView . Very easy to use, works well, it's customisable, has support for sequence of instructions. Solved many issued that [ShowCase view](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)  library has.